Can I lower the height of a sewer vent pipe joint?(2 45°)
1976 home, it had pipes routed through the empty space below/behind the 1-piece shower.
I’ve ripped it out but the 45° joint on the sewer vent pipe is an inch or two too tall to fit any new alcove tub heights.
Can I lower the height of the 2 45° joints bumping out over the stud? I just need it lower to fit in the negative area of an average tub.
I’ve drawn a ‘diagram’ of what seems to be ideal for the measurements I’ve taken, would it be safe to do?
Blue = Current
Red = Potential relocation of joint.


I can not think of a reason why you cannot lower that.  If it is only a vent you can use 90 deg elbows as well.
